# Return count(*) even if 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, group-by

I have the following query:

```
select bb.Name, COUNT(*) as Num from BOutcome bo 
JOIN BOffers bb ON bo.ID = bb.BOutcomeID 
WHERE bo.EventID = 123 AND bo.OfferTypeID = 321 AND bb.NumA > bb.NumB 
GROUP BY bb.Name
```

The table looks like:

```
Name | Num A | Num B
 A   |   10  |   3
 B   |   2   |   3
 C   |   10  |   3
 A   |   9   |   3
 B   |   2   |   3
 C   |   9   |   3
```

The expected output should be:

```
Name | Count
 A   |   2 
 B   |   0  
 C   |   2
```

Because when name is A and C then Num A is bigger to times than Num B and when Name is B, in both records Num A is lower than Num B.

My current output is:

```
Name | Count
 A   |   2 
 C   |   2
```

Because B's output is 0, i am not getting it back in my query.

What is wrong with my query? how should I get it back?

Comment: Have you tried to perform `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: You say "The table looks like:" but your query mentions TWO tables. Can you be more specific please?

Comment: @abatishchev Seriously, did you just leave that as an answer?

Comment: @casperOne: on this site there are approximately 100500 answers worse then this my. Do higher rep users have more strict requirements to their answers? I think this is a good start to search by opself

Comment: @abatishchev A bad answer is a bad answer no matter who posts it.  I think yours got flagged so it got attention.  Go flag the other 100k answers and they will be dealt with too.

Comment: Ido, can you show your table structure and sample data please?  I'm not sure given the info provided that this can be solved.

Comment: Honestly I don't mind it was flagged thus removed. I gave up writing a full answer when got a notification that more answers were added, and they're already fully descriptive.

Comment: @abatishchev No, but *I know* that *you know* better.  That said, don't contribute to the mess, try and make it better, if you see an answer like that, flag it and the moderators will handle it.  And ask follow up questions in a comment!

Comment: I can't believe the amount of time and energy that has been wasted on this question and all of the incorrect answers that have been posted. @Ido will you ***PLEASE*** update the question and clarify the structure and data of the TWO tables!?!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my guess. I think this is a much simpler approach than all of the left/right join hoops people have been spinning their wheels on. Since the output of the query relies only on columns in the left table, there is no need for an explicit join at all:

```
SELECT 
  bb.Name, 
  [Count] = SUM(CASE WHEN bb.NumA > bb.NumB THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -- just FYI, the above could also be written as:
  -- [Count] = COUNT(CASE WHEN bb.NumA > bb.NumB THEN 1 END)
FROM dbo.BOffers AS bb
WHERE EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.BOutcome 
    WHERE ID = bb.BOutcomeID
    AND EventID = 123
    AND OfferTypeID = 321
)
GROUP BY bb.Name;
```

Of course, we're not *really* sure that both Name and NumA/NumB are in the left table, since the OP talks about two tables but only shows one table in the sample data. My guess is based on the query he says is "working" but missing rows because of the explicit join.

Answer (score 0):

Another wild guess. Feel free to downvote:

```
SELECT ba.Name, COUNT(bb.BOutcomeID) as Num 
FROM 
        ( SELECT DISTINCT ba.Name
          FROM 
                  BOutcome AS b
              JOIN
                  BOffers AS ba
                      ON  ba.BOutcomeID  = b.ID
          WHERE b.EventID = 123 
            AND b.OfferTypeID = 321
        ) AS ba
    LEFT JOIN 
        BOffers AS bb 
            ON  AND bb.Name = ba.Name
            AND bb.NumA > bb.NumB
GROUP BY ba.Name ;
```

Comment: I actually get double-counting with this query (I assume because of the double-join).

Comment: Yeah, the `EXISTS` approach looks better. This could be rewritten with first the grouping and then the 2nd Join but this question has tired me.